# Ajax help loading content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I got a problem while using this code (which is in a js named ajax.js)

```
    $(function(){
      $("#loading").hide();

         $("ul#nav a").click(function(){
            page = "content/"+$(this).attr('href')

            $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
               $(this).show()
               })
            $("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
               $(this).hide();

            })

            $(".content").load(page);
            return false;
         })
     })
```

On the index.php first on the head division I include the scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
```

And on body division,this is the main menu navigation

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="page1.php">Here 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.php">Here 2 </a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the code where the content is loaded

```
<div class="content">
  <img src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading..." id="loading" />
  <?php include('content/page1.php'); ?>
</div>
```

This code is working perfectly.But my problem is that inside page1.php I got

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="page3.php">Here 3 </a></li>
  <li><a href="page4.php">Here 4 </a></li>
</ul>
```

and the whole system is not working properly.
If i use the links from the main navigation bar its ok but if i try to use links from any of the other pages its not working.
I tried to load the ajax script on every page.php but still is not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should keep Id for each of the element to different.

Comment: Could you put it all together in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If it the id issue, as @sandeepsure suggests, you could change so that both `ul` have the class `nav` instead, and then you use `.nav` instead of `#nav` for the jQuery selector.

Comment: just replace $("ul#nav a").click(function(){ with $(document).on('click', 'ul#nav a', function(){              your problem will be solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the issue with the click event binding.

You need to bind the click event on nav a because of the page1.php have nav menu so the content is loaded using the ajax but click event is not bind on new menu item.

So create new function called BindClickEvent

```
function BindClickEvent(){
        $("ul#nav a").unbind( "click" );
        $("ul#nav a").bind("click", function(){
            page = "content/"+$(this).attr('href')

            $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
               $(this).show()
               })
            $("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
               $(this).hide();

            })

            $(".content").load(page);
            return false;
         })
}
```

call `BindClickEvent` function in page load and page1.php file content also
So whenever you will add / remove menu call `BindClickEvent` function in ajax call response.

Comment: Ok well i created a new js named bind.js and i use there your code.
On index.php on head section i include the bind.js (and the ajax.js)
on page1.php again i iclude the bind.js

Also on ajax.js before the return false; i call BindClickEvent();

Now when the page is loaded for first time the page3.php or page4.php work.
But if i load the page1.php from the main navigation page3.php or page4.php doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue of delegated function,
just replace

`$("ul#nav a").click(function(){`

with

`$(document).on('click', 'ul#nav a', function(){`

your problem will be solved :)